# Scheme remove from list

Tags: scheme

I need to remove a given digit from a list completely. This would be entered:
`(remove-digit 1 '(1 2 3 '(4556 1)))`

I need to return `(2 3 (4556))`
I can remove from the list with this code:

```
(define (remove-digit digit list)
  (cond ((null? list) list)
        ((= digit (car list)) (remove-digit digit (cdr list)))
        (else (cons (car list) (remove-digit digit (cdr list))))))
```

But cannot remove from the lists in lists. Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(define (rem-dig n ds)
  (cond
    ((list? ds) 
       (remove-digit n (map (lambda(d)(rem-dig n d)) ds)))
    (else ds)))
```

Need to replace the equality predicate from number-specific `=` to the general `equal?`:

```
(define (remove-digit digit list)
  (cond ((null? list) list)
        ((equal? digit (car list)) (remove-digit digit (cdr list)))
        (else (cons (car list) (remove-digit digit (cdr list))))))
```

Testing:

```
(rem-dig 1 '(1 2 3 (4556 1)))
;Value 13: (2 3 (4556))
```

---

If improper, dotted lists are allowed, it should be tweaked,

```
(define (rem-dig n ds)
  (cond
    ((list? ds) 
       (remove-digit n (map (lambda(d)(rem-dig n d)) ds)))
    ((pair? ds)
       (let* ((x  (last-pair ds))
              (y  (cdr x))
              (z  (set-cdr! x ()))
              (ds (rem-dig n ds))
              (x  (last-pair ds)))
         (if (not (equal? n y))
           (set-cdr! x y))
         ds))
    (else ds)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a clause to the `cond` statement, handling (sub)lists:

```
(define (remove-digit digit list)
  (cond ((null? list) list)
        ((eqv? digit (car list)) (remove-digit digit (cdr list)))
        ((list? (car list)) (cons (remove-digit digit (car list)) 
                                  (remove-digit digit (cdr list))))
        (else (cons (car list) (remove-digit digit (cdr list))))))
```

Comment: if `(car list)` is not a number, `(= digit (car list))` will cause an error.

Comment: @Will  Thanks.. Changed to `eqv?` now.

Answer (score 0):

change = to equal?

```
(define (remove-digit digit list)
  (cond ((null? list) list)
        ((equal? digit (car list)) (remove-digit digit (cdr list)))
        (else (cons (car list) (remove-digit digit (cdr list))))))

(display (remove-digit 1 '(1 2 3 (4556 1))))
```